# save preferences for dynamically created multiple checkboxes android

Tags: android, dynamic, checkbox

As part of my App, I am trying to create a customizable checklist. The user gets to select as many as he wants from the default checklist along with adding anad deleting new items in to the list. However, once the items in the list are finalized by the user, the list needs to be saved for when the next time the app is used.

I have tried a couple of methods, none of which have worked. Can somebody please help me with this?
Here is the code:

```
public class Dynamo extends Activity{
@Overrided
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] A = new String[100];
    String[] B = new String[100];
    final CheckBox[] cbx = new CheckBox[100];
    int i,k,j,m,q;
    final int n;

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        A = extras.getStringArray("var");
        i = extras.getInt("var2");
        B = extras.getStringArray("var3");
        k = extras.getInt("var4");

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            cbx[j]  = new CheckBox(this);
            ll.addView(cbx[j]); 
            cbx[j].setText(A[j]);
        }
        for (m=0;m<k;m++)
        {
            cbx[m]  = new CheckBox(this);
            ll.addView(cbx[m]);
            cbx[m].setText(B[m]);
        }
        n=j+m;

        Button delete=new Button(this);
        delete.setText("Delete");
        ll.addView(delete);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for(int p = 0; p < n; p++) {
                if (cbx[p].isChecked())
                {
                    ll.removeView(cbx[p]); 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removing! " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }  
        }});
        this.setContentView(sv);
}
```

Comment: How about now Vyger? Can you please help me now?

Comment: I'm not great with programmatically generated controls. Nor I understand the need of doing such things by code...

Answer (score 0):

you should make your list in xml for consitancy....

private void save() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

```
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.commit();

//you will need the following line for each checkbox you want to save data for.
        editor.putBoolean("CHECKBOX", yourcheckbox.isChecked();
        editor.commit();



    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

also you need this method to load them, call it in onCreate(), but after you initialized the checkboxes

```
private void loadSavedPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager

        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        yourcheckbox.isChecked=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("CHECKBOX", false);

    }
```

Comment: if you want your list to change and be dynamic you will nee an arraylist adapter, and you will need to implement it.

Comment: Well, I'm able to generate , add to and delete from the list without the need of an array adapter. This is the last function left on the list. I do not much time to re-do everything using array adapter again. Can you please give a solution without using XML or Array Adapter?

Comment: the calls above should work as long as you dont use them until after your items are created. so after you make them, im assuming in oncreate, assign them each ids, and then loadPreferences, and then save preferences in onPause.

Comment: No. They are not. Erroneous results are coming out. I guess the complication is because, the list in the current activity is coming based on the information sent from the previous activity. Hence, I think now, that the preferences have to be saved in the previous activity and not here. The way I generated the list is kind of hard-coded, so I'm finding it tough to geenrate the saved prefernces from them. Would you be interested in taking a look at the code?

Comment: yes please, and the logcat output for your error would help as well